# C++ OpenMP: How to use private/protected member variables in a parallel region inside a function member?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

TL;DR: I have a class member function in which there is some parallel code that uses other private or protected class members.

My class structure is similar to this:

```
class ChildClass : public GeneralClass
{
private:
    std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd> edgePotentials;   
protected:
    // Graph structure
    size_t numberOfNodes;
    size_t numberOfEdges;
    vector< vector<size_t> > edges;
    vector< vector<size_t> > containing_edges;   // containing_edges[i] is the list of edges that contain the node i

    // Some intermediate quantities
    std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd> P;
    std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd> RC;

    // Caching decision variables for the above quantities
    std::vector< std::vector<bool> > hasChangedP;
    std::vector< std::vector<bool> > hasChangedRC;

    // A component of the main algorithm (that need to be parallized)
    virtual void computeP(size_t d, const std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd> &X);
public:
    ChildClass();

    // Main algorithm
    virtual double MainAlgorithm() override;
};
```

Now in the member `MainAlgorithm` I call some function that needs to be parallelized:

```
double ChildClass::MainAlgorithm()
{
    /// Initialization
    vector<MatrixXd> X(D);
    ...

    // Main algorithm
    for(size_t d = 0; d < D; d++){
        // Step 1: compute the caching decision variables hasChangedP and hasChangedRC (to see if P and RC need to be re-computed or not)

        // Step 2: Call this function 
        computeP(d, X);

        // Step 3: Update X
    }     
}
```

and the function in question has the following structure:

```
void ChildClass::computeP(size_t d, const vector<MatrixXd> &X)
{
    // for each edge
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(size_t e = 0; e < numberOfEdges; e++){
        size_t i = edges[e][0];
        size_t j = edges[e][1];
        if(hasChangedRC[e][d]){
            RC[e].col(d) = edgePotentials[e]*X[1-d].col(j);
        }
    }

    // now for each node
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(size_t i = 0; i < numberOfNodes; i++){
        if(hasChangedP[d][i]){
            ... compute P[d].col(i) based on RC, edgePotentials, containing_edges...
        }
    }

}
```

Right now the `#pragma omp parallel for` doesn't help at all. I guess that is because the class members (`numberOfNodes, numberOfEdges, RC, edgePotentials, containing_edges`,... can't be shared in the parallel regions?

Could you please help me to resolve this? Thank you so much in advance!

**Update:**

- `numberOfNodes` can go from a few thousands to hundreds of thousands, and `numberOfEdges` is several times `numberOfNodes`.
- As suggested by @zzxyz, I tried to divide the loops into `N` blocks (where `N` is the number of threads). Instead of

  ```
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for(size_t e = 0; e < numberOfEdges; e++){
       // Code for each edge here
  }
  ```

I used:

```
    size_t threads = 8;
    size_t p = floor(numberOfEdges/threads);

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(size_t b = 0; b < threads; b++){
        size_t first = b*p;
        size_t last = (b+1)*p - 1;
        if(b >= threads - 1){
            last = numberOfEdges - 1;
        }
        for(size_t e = first; e <= last; e++){
            // Code for each edge here
        }
    }
```

And similarly for the loop over the nodes. However this does not help neither. (And as pointed out later by @zzxyz, this is something OpenGM already does automatically for us).

Comment: In order of importance, 1)  When you say "doesn't help at all", are you talking about performance?  2)  Are you still getting the correct results?  3)  Are you SURE you are still getting the correct results?  I'll assume "yes" to all of these and attempt to explain why I think that is in my next comment.

Comment: @zzxyz Thanks. 1) Yes, I was talking about performance. 2) Yes I obtained exactly the same results (as without `#pragma omp parallel`). 3) Yes, I have checked again (by running the program twice, with and without `#pragma omp parallel`), and I obtained exactly the same results, except that with `#pragma omp parallel` enabled it took more time.

Comment: How big is `numberOfEdges` and `numberOfNodes`? The amount of work in each loop iteration seems very light, so I'd generally think these numbers would have to be quite huge to compensate for the loop scheduling overhead.

Comment: @TeamUpvote `numberOfNodes` can go from a few thousands to hundreds of thousands (and `numberOfEdges` is several times `numberOfNodes`). I have checked again and for very large number of nodes (~100000) it seems adding `#pragma omp parallel for` can yield a very slightly better performance (that is very insignificant), while I expected it to be several times faster (with 8 threads).

Comment: @zzxyz Please see my last comment to TeamUpvote.

Comment: Yeah, @TeamUpvote beat me to it.  For each of these iterations, you're dealing with thread scheduling overhead to....perform *very* few instructions.  To get a performance benefit, you need to do more work in each iteration.  There's OVERALL thread scheduling overhead, and then there's overhead for each iteration.  It's small, but again, you are doing very little work in each iteration.

Comment: @Khue - You could try nesting your loops.  outer `i=i+100`;  Then have an inner j loop that is NOT parallel that iterates through those 100 records.  Or a thousand.  Or maybe you can find a more elegant way of breaking up the work.  Let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: @zzxyz Well I think hundreds of thousands is already quite huge to benefit from parallelization. Moreover, the operations at each iteration are maxtrix/vector multiplication (and also vector addition), which is expensive.

Comment: @Khue It might also be due to the nature of your memory access patterns. I'm far from an expert on cache coherence and luckily often work with data structures that are already very straightforward in terms of memory layouts to access them in a very simple kind of contiguous/sequential fashion. But if possible you might see about rearranging the memory layouts and/or access patterns if possible to favor accessing data in a more contiguous way. I'm afraid it's kind of trial and error with me for this stuff, but usually I get a decent 2.5x...

Comment: ... boost on average on my i7 (4 cores), sometimes 4x+, but maybe 2.5x on average. But again I'm working with very cache-friendly data and access patterns. There was a time though when I started with OMP and TBB where I was often making things slower with parallel loops until I got the hang of it. Mostly getting the hang of it boiled down to favoring meatier work and/or more iterations, and making sure the memory access patterns are reasonably cache-friendly.

Comment: @zzxyz I see the idea of nesting loops (optimally having `n` outer loops where `n` is the number of threads, right?), but isn't that something OpenMP should optimize for us already? (I mean instead of running the loop on a single thread, OpenGM divides them into blocks so that each block will run on a separate thread.)

Comment: @Khue - You might give it a shot just to see.  Fairly easy to test.  And if your matrices are not screen-sized, you might be shocked at how fast modern processors can tear through moderately-sized ones compared to even a few conditionals (`if` statements).  And Team Upvote makes a great point about memory access possibly being a limiting factor.  That is a much more difficult fix, potentially.

Comment: @TeamUpvote Thanks. I will try to dive into what you are saying. So, there's nothing to do with the private/protected member variables, as I initially thought, right?

Comment: @Khue Sometimes it helps to break things up into multiple passes as well to recognize ways to favor those chunkier outer loops with more cache-friendly access patterns. Like I don't understand your example that well but if you do two or more passes through `d`, you might be able to parallelize on `d` rather than, say, `e`. Or it might be helpful to loop through `e` and then `d` in the inner loop if possible. As for private/protected variables, nope AFAIK. I have never encountered any problem with those -- OMP isn't that smart and doesn't do things like insert locks or anything implicitly.

Comment: @zzxyz Certainly, it's worth trying. I will get back. Thanks!

Comment: @Khue - Regarding the optimization, I doubt it, although I'm not familiar with OpenMP in particular.  Each and every iteration of your parallel loop likely incurs overhead not associated with the single-threaded version.  I could be wrong.

Comment: @TeamUpvote Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Khue Cheers! As a very basic example of "cache-friendly", take an image processing algorithm where the parallel loop is looping through *columns* of the image in a vertical fashion on the inner loop while modifying pixels. That's not very cache friendly since there's a big stride to get from one row (scanline) of the image to the next, but also there will be data shared across cache lines in multiple threads with overlapping reads/writes of the same memory region. That might actually get worse in performance with multithreading than without... but if you, instead, make the algorithm...

Comment: @Khue loop over rows/scanlines of the image in parallel while the inner loop is accessing pixels in a horizontal/contiguous fashion, then you can easily see substantial speed improvements with the parallel outer loop. In some cases it can also help to transpose an image/matrix in advance before looping over it and then transpose again after.

Comment: @TeamUpvote Thanks. I see the idea, but I'm afraid that in my case the memory access is very cache-unfriendly :( I have tried dividing the iterations into `n` blocks (where `n` is the number of threads), and it seems to help (but no so much). I will try tomorrow to run the code on a 40-thread cluster to see if the speed-up is clearer.

Comment: @zzxyz I will update tomorrow. Please see my last comment. Thanks again!

Comment: Please edit your question to include the clarifications from the comments such that it contains the necessary information in the question itself without reading through all the comments.

Comment: @Khue - I went here: https://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/#LoopConstructFor and OMP is pretty impressive.  It's certainly capable of having a single thread execute several loop iterations in one go.  Looks like you can be pretty explicit, specifying "chunk size", and it might be smart enough to limit on threads anyway.  Or, to put it simply, I *think* I was wrong about the optimization.

Comment: @zzxyz Yes, that's what I thought initially. I tried your suggestion anyway, but it did not help (please see my update).

Comment: Here comes the boss @Zulan :D I have updated the question, please have a look! Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: @Khue -- Hmmm, this is very interesting : https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicMultiThreading.html .  Have you tried removing your explicit use of OpenMP, and just watching your processor usage?  Perhaps eigen is already exploiting all your processors...

Comment: `top` can do it.  Tapping `1` should cycle the cpu display, or there's a thread display mode (`H`) if you're on a multi-user system where this isn't useful.  Probably you already know that, but in case not :)

Comment: @zzxyz I already checked that. When running with 1 thread only 1 thread was used, and when running with 8 threads, all the 8 threads were used. Still the final running times are not so different. I guess there is a bottleneck at the memory access.

Comment: @Khue - Ah shoulda known.  You've been pretty diligent :)  Worth a shot.  I personally would probably play around with explicitly enabling eigen parallelization (and disabling mine) and explicitly disabling it (and enabling mine), but it is likely to be a waste of time :)